# release static WCF resource

Tags: c#, wcf

I have declared static resource as follows:

```
public DiagnosticModule : TestModule
{
      private static ChannelFactory<IDiagnosticService> _diagnosticsChannelFactory;
      private static ChannelFactory<IDiagnosticService> DiagnosticsChannelFactory => _diagnosticsChannelFactory ?? throw new FaultException<ApciFault>(new Fault{ FaultMessage = "Diagnostic Service Channel is NOT initialized yet" },string.Empty); 

      static DiagnosticModule()
      {
         .............
         _diagnosticsChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IDiagnosticService>(new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None),endPoint);
         .............
      }

       public static void func1(...)
       {
             IDiagnosticService v5DiagnosticInformationClient = null;  

             try
             {
                  v5ClearDiagnosticInformationClient = DiagnosticsChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

                  ...................

                  ((IClientChannel)v5ClearDiagnosticInformationClient).Close();
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                  ((IClientChannel)v5ClearDiagnosticInformationClient).Abort();
             }              
       }
```

All the functions within the DiagnosticModule class are static and I am looking for a way to call so that I can close the factory I have instantiated inside the static constructor:

```
      DiagnosticsChannelFactory.Close();
```

Where to call the above snippet inside the class ?

Comment: You can add the ChannelClose static method in the DiagnosticModule: public static void ChannelClose() {
            DiagnosticsChannelFactory.Close();
        }. Then call this method externally to close the diagnosticchannelfactory.

Comment: I hope that this static method can be invoked from the PoweerShell Script. Is it possible to check if the channel factory is alive before trying to close it ?

Comment: The channel factory has the state property to view the status of the channel object. You can refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.communicationstate?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1.